# Bug na exibição dos motivos no modal de fechamento

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Os modais para se votar o fechamento de uma pergunta, quando esta já possui votos, são exibidos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde as descrições dos motivos com votos ficam sobre o texto do próprio motivo.

Inspecionando os elementos, é possível verificar que este elemento

```
#pane-main ul li lable span.action-desc
```

Possui o atributo `padding-top` zerado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enquanto o mesmo elemento, nos motivos que não possuem votos, tal atributo possui o valor `23px`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tem o *report* no metão: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357243/1452488

Comment: Já arrumaram o bug